# Increasing the spacing between plotting texts in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hi is there a way I could increase the spacing between the lines for the function:

`plt.axhline(-100, color = 'purple', linewidth =1.4, linestyle='--')`

The output gives the lines on the graph that looks like `---`

However my intended output is `- - -`

Comment: Maybe "loosely dashed" is what you need? See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html). But you can do any style you want of course; this is just something the devs made to show how to make custom linestyles

Comment: @user8408080 good spot. I deleted my answer, but the best option for NOT passing a tuple is `linestyle='-.'`. I didn't know that there were so many customization options, I have bookmarked this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You could specify [dashed line styles](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) by providing a dash tuple `(offset, (on_off_seq))`:

Example:

```py
ax.axhline(threshold, color="red", lw=2, alpha=0.7, linestyle=(0, (5, 10)))
```